# What does "01011" mean in the Collectives page image?

Tags: discussion, images, collectives

There is an image on the [Stack Overflow Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/) page. In the image, there are some binary codes are displayed.
One of the binary codes, I'm able to convert as text is "to-do". But there is one more binary code as "01011", simply converting it to return as "11".

Is there any meaning for the code "01011" or are they simply referring to "11" here? If it is referring to "11" only, any special reason for that?
The image creator should be aware of the reason, so just want to understand the meaning.

**Image for reference:**

> [image: Stack Overflow Collectives page]

Comment: Why can it not just be some arbitrary binary..? Why does it **need** to have meaning? Should, therefore, the date 01 January 1970 also have some unknown meaning too, as it's the date on the calendar?

Comment: @Larnu That's UNIX EPOCH

Comment: It's the date it *starts* on (traditionally), @Dharman , but that's not the point I am making here.

Comment: Also, the complete lack of coffee (stains) in the picture suggests that these folks might not be programmers at all.

Comment: Maybe the sign in the background is supposed to say "Jolt Cola"?

Comment: More disturbingly... why does the woman on the right appear to have no knees? :p

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-01011-mean-in-binary

Comment: There is also an obvious lack of stale, months-old pepperoni underneath the potted plant.

Comment: Even the image knows the old vote buttons are superior

Comment: The plants seem to be neglected.

Comment: [Stack Overflow reference to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-vim).

Comment: A "burning" question.

Comment: To my knowledge, it has no special meaning, but I’ve pinged our design team to confirm. Hope to have an official answer after the holiday weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 01011 doesn't mean anything! The 'to-do' was meant as a joke that the illustration was unfinished, but also a reference to all the 'to-do's we often have in our code.